# Diagonalisable real matrix. Conclusion

Tags: linear-algebra

A matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ is diagonalisable on $\mathbb{R}$. Then:

**a.**  characteristic polynomial of $A$ is product of polynomials degree $1$ with real coefficients

**b.** matrix $A^2$ is also diagonalisable

**c.** $A=A^T$  .

**b.** is obviously true, we know that $A^2=(PDP^{-1})^2 = PD^2P^{-1}$  Due to $D^2$ is still diagonal then **b.** is true.
**a.**
We know that $A$ is similar to some diagonal matrix $D$. Therefore, $A$ has the same characteristic polynomial as $D$, so it is product of $(x-\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is any eigenvalue. Lets consider:
$A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 0  \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2& 0 \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0& 1  \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right)$ is diagonalisable, but $P_A(x)=(x-2)^2$.  So it is not prodcut of **degree 1** polynomials. Hence, **a.** is not true.

What about these solutions ?  Can you help me solve **c.** ?

Comment: For a and your example, $(x-2)^2=(x-2)(x-2)$, then $P_A$ is product of polynomials degree 1 with real coefficients. (they are the same I agree but the assumption does nos require them to be distincts)

Comment: c is saying that every real diagonalizable matrix is symmetric. Do you really believe this?

Comment: So, only **b.** is correct. No, I don't believe it.  Nevertheless, Can you help me solve **a.** and **c.** ?

Comment: a) is true. Indeed, the characteristic polynomial factorizes as $\prod_{\lambda} (x- \lambda)$, where $\{ \lambda \}$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ (i.e. the diagonal entries of $D$).

Comment: From what you know that $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: As Crostul commented and since clearly all the roots of the char. pol. must be real (as the matrix is defined over the reals and is diagonalizable), (a) is trivially true *because it isn't written there the word* "different" or "distinct" .

Comment: So each real matrix which is diagonalisable has only real eigenvalues ?

Comment: @Happyman Each **real** matrix which is diagonalizable **over the reals** has to have only real roots.

Comment: So over the reals is key assumption ? Without this it is not true ?  (the same assumption about real entries in diagonalisable matrix is too weak. Yeah ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $c)$ , just take the matrix $\pmatrix{1&2\\3&4}$ which is not symmetric , but real diagonalizable.

Comment: What about **b.** ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a)